# Module Federation - exclude React from MFE?

Tags: webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

If my MFE Shell App is the one that's already loading React, is there a reason for why i shouldn't include React under Webpack's `externals` (i.e so it doesn't get bundled with the MFE) as opposed to include it in the Webpack Module Federation `shared` config which means it'd be included in the MFE bundle?